# call jquery fom php script

Tags: php, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--//
    // on DOM ready
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#current_rev").html("v"+$.jnotify.version);
        $("a.example").bind("click", function (e){
            // prevent default behavior
            e.preventDefault();

            var $ex = $($(this).attr("href")), code = $.trim($ex.text());

            // execute the sample code
            $.globalEval(code);
        });

        // style switcher
        $("button.css_switcher").click(function (){
            switchCSS(this.title);
        });
    });



    //-->
    </script>
```

Instead of using click events like `<a href="#example-1" class="example">[Run]</a> and <a href="#example-2" class="example">[Run]</a>`

How can I call events if a condition is true or false?

```
<?php
if (true){
<a href="#example-1" class="example">[Run]</a>}else{
<a href="#example-2" class="example">[Run]</a>}
?>
```

Comment: jQuery is javascript, which runs on the client. PHP runs on the server. Think about that for a while.

Comment: I can't help but wonder if we have an incomplete code sample here.  Where's this css switcher button?  What is supposed to happen when one of those links is clicked?

Comment: Its quite confusing what you are trying to achive. You can output javascript code from php, but you cannot call a javascript function from php, because what tdammers wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You mean "trigger" events? Your question is a bit confusing.

You can just add `$("#example-1").trigger("click")` to the document.ready function.
So if a condition is true on the server side it will do something on the client side when the page gets sent to the user.

Make sure you attach the click event **before** you trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
 // all event binds and other code
<?php
 if ( $trigger ) {
  echo "$('#".$element_id."').trigger( 'click' )";
 }
?>
}
```

Make `$trigger` a true false and give all your links ids and pass the id as `$element_id`

Comment: Why doesn't the php part show up! :S  How do you include php code?

Comment: you have to use markdown to indicate that it's code, not pre tags.  I've fixed it for you